# How to do a WFS version 2.0.0 GetFeature request with OL3?

Tags: openlayers, wfs, getfeature

How to obtain information about the feature WFS layer in different versions of [WFS 1.0.0 / 1.1.0 / 2.0.0](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) ?

The OL documentation says

> Feature format for reading and writing data in the WFS format. By default, supports WFS version 1.1.0. You can pass a GML format as option if you want to read a WFS that contains GML2 (WFS 1.0.0). Also see ol.format.GMLBase which is used by this format.

Ok, example [WFS - GetFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html) is performed in the version 1.1.0

```
var f = ol.format.ogc.filter;
var wfs = new ol.format.WFS();
wfs.writeGetFeature({
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
    featureNS: 'http://openstreemap.org',
    featurePrefix: 'osm',
    featureTypes: ['water_areas'],
    outputFormat: 'application/json',
    filter: f.and(
        f.like('name', 'Mississippi*'),
        f.equalTo('waterway', 'riverbank')
    )
});
```

But it always forms a request in WFS version 1.1.0.
How to form GetFeature request in WFS versions 2.0.0 using writeGetFeature function?

Comment: Are you just looking for http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GML.html ?

Comment: Alas, No. Sample XML generation for the XML for WFS 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

A question on the OL3 developers forum, from June 2014, tells us that whilst there is support for WFS 2 in OL 2, there is no such support for WFS 2 in OL3!

[WFS / GML versioning support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/fD34lChfvvc)

Answer (score 1):

I may be a bit late, but as I myself was looking for how to change the version in `writeGetFeature` to `2.0.0` in the current version of OL (v7.2.2) maybe someone else will find this answer useful.
It turns out that specifying the version in the `WFS` constructor allows `writeGetFeature` to be written in the desired form:

```
import { WFS } from 'ol/format.js';
import {
    and as andFilter,
    like as likeFilter,
    equalTo as equalToFilter,
} from 'ol/format/filter.js';

const featureRequest = new WFS({ version: '2.0.0' })
    .writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featureNS: 'http://openstreemap.org',
        featurePrefix: 'osm',
        featureTypes: [ 'water_areas' ],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        filter: andFilter(
            likeFilter('name', 'Mississippi*'),
            equalToFilter('waterway', 'riverbank'),
        ),
    });

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest));
```

results with:

```xml
<GetFeature
    service="WFS" version="2.0.0" outputFormat="application/json"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0">
  <Query typeNames="osm:water_areas" srsName="EPSG:3857" xmlns:osm="http://openstreemap.org">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0">
      <And>
        <PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escapeChar="!">
          <ValueReference>name</ValueReference>
          <Literal>Mississippi*</Literal>
        </PropertyIsLike>
        <PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ValueReference>waterway</ValueReference>
          <Literal>riverbank</Literal>
        </PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </And>
    </Filter>
  </Query>
</GetFeature>
```